# Ошибка Android Studio "не поддерживает тип аннотаций..."

Tags: java, android, обработка-ошибок

[Код.](http://textuploader.com/d5fwt)

```
package zaynukov.com.project4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public double pervoeChislo (){
        EditText chislo1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chislo1);
        return Double.parseDouble(chislo1.getText().toString());
    }

    public double vtoroeChislo (){
        EditText chislo2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chislo2);
        return Double.parseDouble(chislo2.getText().toString());
    }


    View.OnClickListener OnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            power power = new power();
            TextView resultat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultat);

            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.plusButton:
                    resultat.setText(power.resPlus(pervoeChislo(),vtoroeChislo()));
                    break;
                case R.id.minusButton:
                    resultat.setText(power.resMinus(pervoeChislo(),vtoroeChislo()));
                    break;
                case R.id.umnButton:
                    resultat.setText(power.resUmn(pervoeChislo(),vtoroeChislo()));
                    break;
                case R.id.delButton:
                    resultat.setText(power.resDel(pervoeChislo(),vtoroeChislo()));
                    break;
                case R.id.korenButton:
                    resultat.setText(power.resKoren(pervoeChislo()));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button plusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
        Button minusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
        Button umnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.umnButton);
        Button delButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delButton);
        Button korenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.korenButton);

        plusButton.setOnClickListener();
        umnButton.setOnClickListener();
        minusButton.setOnClickListener();
        delButton.setOnClickListener();
        korenButton.setOnClickListener();

    }
}
```

Файл build.gradle содержит:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "zaynukov.com.project4"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Android Studio выдаёт ошибки:

> Error:(57, 6) error: type annotations are not supported in -source 1.7
>   (use -source 8 or higher to enable type annotations)
>
> Error:(51, 5) error: illegal start of expression
>
> Error:(51, 14) error: ';' expected
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Как без кода мы вам можем подсказать?

Comment: Добавил код (см. описание).

Comment: Покажите содержимое `build.gradle`.

Comment: Пожалуйста. См. описание.

Comment: У Вас в проекте два файла `build.gradle`: один уровня проекта, другой – уровня модуля. Вот мне второй нужен.

Comment: Странно. А если создать пустой проект, то он тоже не соберется? Попробуйте, как вариант, в свойствах проекта поставить галочку `use embedded jdk`.

Comment: У вас в коде по ссылке нет `;` после объявления поля с присвоением экземпляра анонимного класса, а надо бы.